# Failed to connect to http://localhost:3001/graphql

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

Hi friends thank you for your help, I’m working with Strapi and I have cofigured to work with GraphQL,
but my Next JS App show that error
I entered to the url: http://localhost:3001/graphql on my web brower and works perfectly
but in the Next App doesn’t work
my partners use Windows and me Mac , but I don’t know if this is tha problem

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code. It would be difficult to help out with the current screenshots you have added.